# GWT 2.4: "An internal compiler exception occurred" in project that uses Hibernate for Bean Validation

Tags: gwt, bean-validation, gwt2, hibernate-validator

It's been about 5 hrs since I decided to use JSR 303 Bean Validation in my GWT project and I gotta say I can't even express (politely) how deeply unsatisfied I am with [lame documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation) on the subject on Google's website.

I really hope you guys can help me.

I followed [this blog post](http://gglwebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/12/client-side-bean-validation-with-gwt.html) to add client-side bean validation to my project. Unfortunately it worked only once and threw an exception in runtime saying that I need to add Hibernate Validation sources to class path. I fixed that and decided to remassage my dependencies a little too (biggest mistake of my life) but I couldn't make it work ever again.

I can't play with Validation sample from GWT SDK either because it's uncompilable because it has two implementations of class `ServerValidator`. Weird.

So to simplify my question I created dummy GWT application using project wizard of IntelliJ IDEA.

I added following elements to module xml:

```
<inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"/>
<replace-with class="com.mySampleApplication.client.ClientValidatorFactory">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory"/>
</replace-with>
```

Created `ClientValidatorFactory`:

```
package com.mySampleApplication.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.validation.client.AbstractGwtValidatorFactory;
import com.google.gwt.validation.client.GwtValidation;
import com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.AbstractGwtValidator;

import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public class ClientValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory
{
    @GwtValidation(value = {Organization.class}, groups = {Default.class, ClientGroup.class})
    public interface GwtValidator extends Validator
    {
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractGwtValidator createValidator()
    {
        return GWT.create(GwtValidator.class);
    }
}
```

And in `onModuleLoad()` method I added this single line which causes compiler to blow up

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

And finally I used following jars which I copied **from Validation sample of GWT SDK**.

```
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final-sources.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

But when I compile my project it gives following meaningless error:

[image]

In detailed GWT compiler log I see this:

```
Loaded 2315 units from persistent store.
   Found 2282 cached units.  Used 2282 / 2282 units from cache.
   Added 0 units to persistent cache.
   Validating newly compiled units
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/engine/ConstraintViolationImpl_CustomFieldSerializer.java'
         Line 33: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/engine/ValidationSupport.java'
         Line 43: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/super/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/EmailValidator.java'
         Line 25: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/super/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/ScriptAssertValidator.java'
         Line 26: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/super/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/URLValidator.java'
         Line 26: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/externals/gwt/gwt-user.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/super/org/hibernate/validator/engine/PathImpl.java'
         Line 72: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.engine.NodeImpl; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Why can't it find classses? I have `hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final-sources.jar` in my classpath.

Any thoughts ?

I uploaded my project **[here](http://www.box.com/s/gpvp2hmpxeajyryy5glo)** if you guys want to play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed, guys. Error was caused by lack of hibernate validation sources in classpath because of bug in IntelliJ IDEA. Details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630298/intellij-idea-how-can-i-make-sources-of-dependent-libraries-to-be-available-in).

Comment: Infinite loop! Your link goes to this page. :\