# IntelliJ IDEA: How can I make sources of dependent libraries to be available in classpath on compilation?

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, classpath

How can I make sources of dependent libraries to be available in classpath on compilation ?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 11.

When I add Global Library to module and artifact IDE never copies sources and javadocs. That makes sense because they are not needed in runtime. But I need them in compile time.

Interestingly though IDEA **makes** sources available if I add dependency as folder. I guess in this case it doesn't differentiate what sits in that folder. Odd.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i solved this issue in maven config by specifying another dependency to hibernate-validator  one with sources and one without.

the one with sources i defined:

classifier: **sources**
 scope: **provided**

EX:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I would not have guessed that one. The GWT official validation docs could have told us that, come on guys!

Comment: Whoever reads this answer, could you please confirm in comments this solution worked for you too ? I don't have GWT project nearby to check.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug that sources attached to a library are not used on GWT compilation. This bug is fixed in [IDEA 11.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP).

Comment: I'm using exactly this build actually :) 116.32. Do you have URL to submitted bug? Do I need to do anything special in UI to make it work ? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sample project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/GwtGLBindingDemo2.zip, related bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80724. Library is correctly built with sources attached: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/screens/snap1074-1331297703.png.